# EXTRA_OUTPUT ignored on Eris, causes data to return null on G1

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

So I'm trying to launch the Camera activity using the following code:

```
//In public void captureImage()
...
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                      Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/image.jpg")));
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

And then to handle the result:

```
//In onActivityResult()
...
case REQUEST_CAMERA:
  Intent intent = new Intent (CurrentScreen.this, NextScreen.this);
  intent.putExtra(data);
  startActivity(intent);
  CurrentScreen.this.finish();
...
```

Where I use `intent.putExtra(data)` to attach the small bitmap to the intent, and use it as a thumbnail in the next activity, and the full sized file is supposedly saved as `/sdcard/image.jpg`.

This is the expected behavior (according to the documentation), to have a small bitmap for a thumbnail, and a large file saved.  However when testing this on a G1 and an Eris, I have been seeing some strange behavior.

On the G1:

- Although the resultCode shows RESULT_OK, the intent data that is returned to the result handler is null.
- Also EXTRA_OUTPUT seems to be completely ignored, I have no idea where it is saving the image.

On the Eris:

- The intent data comes back OK
- EXTRA_OUTPUT is also ignored, but it is saving the images to the regular media store at `/sdcard/dcim/100media`

So my question is this: is there any way to get consistent behavior for what I am trying to do using the standard camera activity?  I could write up a custom activity to try and get it to work the way I want, but I'd prefer to avoid that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have answers to your question as I am new to the Java/Android development world.  But I am attempting something similar to what you are doing, except I want to simply take the picture then attach it to an Email message.

I implemented part of your example and was able to verify that the camera created the file I specified and that if I use the same file name for the next picture that it overwrites the previous file which is what I would expect.

But what I was really going to say is perhaps you will have to test if the pat "/sdcard/..." actually exists or not.  Also you could possibly simplify your process by passing the path to the next activity.

Good Luck,

Jamie Irwin

Comment: I actually did have the checking set up in my application, but I omitted that part in my post to keep things shorter.  What I am going to end up having to do is most likely write my own camera activity because from what I have been reading the inconsistency is due to the different camera applications that different manufacturers include with their handsets.  Not all of them handle the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent properly.